# Omit fields while extending interface typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger

I am trying to extend ISampleB interface and Omit few values from it like below. I am unaware if i am performing anything wrong

```
export interface ISampleA extends Omit<ISampleB, 'fieldA' | 'fieldB' | 'fieldC' | 'fieldD' | 'fieldE'> {
    fieldB?: string
    fieldA?: string
    fieldC?: string
    fieldD: number
    fieldE?: number
}
```

My swagger generator throws error like below

```
There was a problem resolving type of 'ISampleA'.

ode_modules/typescript-rest-swagger/dist/metadata/methodGenerator.js:83
                throw new Error("Error generate parameter method: '" + controllerId.text + "." + methodId.text + "' argument: " + parameterId.text + " " + e);
Error: Error generate parameter method: 'abc' argument: fields Error: No type found for Omit
```

Comment: I actually am not sure if the thrown error comes from this, but I think omitting properties from an interface and re-defining them in it's extended interface doesn't work.

Comment: Why not extract the actual commonalities to a third interface they both extend?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I cannot change the main interface as it's used in many places and will have to modify lots of test cases.

Comment: Why does it matter where it's used? ISampleB would still be the same result, it just makes ISampleA easier to define.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Sure let me try it. Is my way of doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly, but with such an abstract example and no further context it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Exclude<ISampleB, 'fieldA' | 'fieldB' | 'fieldC' | 'fieldD' | 'fieldE'>`

For more info you may visit https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion

Comment: argument: fields Error: No type found for Exclude